# python os.system() and subprocess.call() generate 32512 or 256 errors

Tags: python, os.system

I'm trying to run a command line program "oconv" from python which is expected to takes several other files as input and generate an output file scene.oct.

I tried both the **os.system()** and **subprocess.call()** functions

However, I either got no output or an incomplete output file.

The 1st type of error code is **32512** or **127**, meaning "**Key has expired**", and the 2nd type of error code is **256** or **1**, meaning "**Operation not permitted**".

The strange thing is that all the 4 types of command line string combinations tested can run with no problem in the Terminal of Mac OS X.

I have no idea why this happens as the test is done on a newly reinstalled and updated Macbook Pro with OS X Marvericks and Python 2.7.5. And the relevant environmental path variable is already specified in both the **~/.bash_profile** and **~/.profile** (I'm admin in this case).

The python code I'm using for test is shown below, which includes four combinations between long/short cmd string and with/without full cmd path:

```
import os
import subprocess

### 1. long cmd str, no cmd path (no output, error code: 32512 or 127, meaning Key has expired)
##cmd = "oconv /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/materials.mat /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/sky.rad /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/scene.rad  >  /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/scene.oct"
##os.system(cmd)
##subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

### 2. short cmd str, no cmd path (no output, error code: 32512 or 127, meaning Key has expired)
##cmd = 'oconv ./materials.mat ./sky.rad ./scene.rad  > ./scene.oct'
##os.system(cmd)
##subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

### 3. long cmd str, full cmd path (can get incomplete output, error code: 256 or 1, meaning Operation not permitted)
##cmd = '/Applications/Radiance_4_3_a_1/bin/oconv /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/materials.mat /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/sky.rad /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/scene.rad  >  /Volumes/ZJ_WD_2TB_1/_ZJ_Urban_Toolkit_v003/glare_analysis/scene.oct'
##os.system(cmd)
##subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

### 4. short cmd str, full cmd path (can get incomplete output, error code: 256 or 1, meaning Operation not permitted)
##cmd = '/Applications/Radiance_4_3_a_1/bin/oconv ./materials.mat ./sky.rad ./scene.rad  > ./scene.oct'
###os.system(cmd)
##subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: I don't understand how another user Yu Hao can edit my post and delete my words expression gratitude! This is just rude and unacceptable, even if Yu Hao is a webmaster or forum manager!

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow.com, after you appreciate [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), check [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267387/142039) and have nice time.